# Does ember-power-select has a feature that mark as selected when a user input text that is not on the record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a scenario where a user can input text and when he press `Enter` key it will tagged as selected. Question, `how will I show the input text that should show as selected when I press Enter?` Example: I typed `Miguel` and press enter it should show as one of the selected records

Addon: https://ember-power-select.com/docs/multiple-selection

[image]

`/template.hbs`

```
<PowerSelectMultiple
  @searchEnabled={{true}}
  @options={{this.names}}
  @selected={{this.name}}
  @onInput={{fn this.foo}}
  @onKeydown={{fn this.baz}}
  @placeholder="Select some names..."
  @onChange={{fn (mut this.name)}} as |name|>
  {{name}}
</PowerSelectMultiple>
```

`/component.js`

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { action } from "@ember/object";
import { tracked } from "@glimmer/tracking";

export default class extends Controller {
  @tracked
  fooBarBazList = [];

  @tracked
  fooBarBazSelectedFromInput = "";

  names = ['Stefan', 'Mike', 'Tomster', 'Pluto'];

  @action
  foo(value) {
    this.fooBarBazSelectedFromInput = value;
  }

  @action
  baz(value, event) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
      let list = this.fooBarBazList;
      let selected = this.fooBarBazSelectedFromInput;
      list.pushObject(selected);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not builtin in the PowerSelectMultiple component. But it may be available in any of the addons which was built based on the PowerSelect addon.
Refer this [link](https://ember-power-select.com/addons) for supported addons.

Your requirement can be solved using the below addon,
https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select-with-create